# I used redux.. i dispatch data successfully. i try to get data other page. Its shows error like Uncaught TypeError: undefined (reading 'category')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

my code .

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function ProductDetail() {

    const product =  useSelector((state)=>state)
    const datas = product.allProducts.products.Data
    console.log('data',datas )
  return (
  )
}
```

this code executed correctly and gave correct output.. but i want `const datas = product.allProducts.products.Data.category`

when i try to get category data its shows error like      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'category') .

my json data

```
"Data": {
        "banner": [
            {
                "BannerId": 1,
                "BannerImage": "image 10_1650873105.png",
                "BannerTitle": "product banner1",
                "BannerDescr": "The products with 50% offer1"
            }
        ],
        "category": [
            {
                "CatId": 23,
                "CatName": "laptop",
                "CatImage": "kari-shea-1SAnrIxw5OY-unsplash_1650877809.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide name of slice to get the data out of it, i.e.

```
`const product =  useSelector((state)=>state.nameOfTheSlice)`
```

[here is example from docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples)

If you can provide the details of you product slice that would help to tackle in details.